# Automatic drop-down list causes unreadable content at next opening of the file

Tags: vba, excel, dropdown

My boss just asked me to create automatic drop-down lists in an Excel 2010 file, following the content of each cell. So far I have written the following code:

```
Public Const vers = "Version, Actual 2016, Actual 2015,Budget 2017, Budget 2016, Budget 2015, LE3 2016, LE2 2016"
Public Const perio = "Period, YTD January N, YTD February N, YTD March N, YTD April N, YTD May N, YTD June N, YTD July N, YTD August N, YTD September N, YTD October N, YTD November N, YTD December N"

Sub MBforall()
Set allinfo = Range("a1", Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
On Error GoTo alinea
Set listesval = allinfo.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
If Not listesval Is Nothing Then
  listesval.Validation.Delete
  GoTo endlinea
End If
alinea:
Set textesall = allinfo.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
textesall.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Dim clsMB(11) As String
clsMB(0) = vers
clsMB(1) = perio
For Each cell In textesall
  For i = 0 To 10
    Dim strMB As String
    strMB = clsMB(i)
    If InStr(1, strMB, LTrim(cell.Value)) > 0 Then
      With cell.Validation
      .Delete
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
      xlBetween, Formula1:=strMB
      .IgnoreBlank = True
      .InCellDropdown = True
      .InputTitle = ""
      .ErrorTitle = ""
      .InputMessage = ""
      .ErrorMessage = ""
      .ShowInput = True
      .ShowError = True
    End With
  End If
  Next
Next cell
endlinea:
End Sub
```

At least it works, and it does exactly what I want to.

However, when I close a file in which I've just used this macro, next time I open it I get:

> Excel has encountered some unreadable content, do you want to get it
>   recovered?

When I say yes, it seems Excel just rehabilitate the older version of my file, deleting all the previous modifications. If I say no, it doesn't open the file.

Is there a way to fix this unreadable content before I save and close the file without deleting the drop-down lists if possible?

Comment: I put your code into a new workbook.  Put some text in column A, selected the text and ran the macro.  I end up with a group of cells with the same pick list in them.  Design intent, right?  Then I saved and closed the file, reopened it, and had no error message.  The validation rules are still there.  No unreadable content.  Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem.  The code works.  Maybe you have a reference to another file that's corrupt?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I'm pretty sure the file is not corrupted as long as I don't launch the macro. I wonder if it could come from the file extension or the Excel version. Otherwise it might come from the settings. But there's still a chance that the problem comes from the macro, because when I build the drop down list manually, there's no problem with it when I close and reopen the file.

Comment: What I meant was, do you have a reference (in the VBA editor, under tools, references) to a library, or another workbook, that might be corrupt?  I've tried it again; saved it as .xls, .xlsm, and .xlsb, and I can't reproduce your problem.   Sorry, I think you should look outside the macro at something else.... maybe check if you have a lot of styles or custom formats?  I'm reaching.  Sorry, I've got nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found the answer to my own question !

My problem came from the length of the strings I intended to create : a variable of type String SHOULD NEVER exceed a **255 characters length** !
Since then, I have shortened the strings and everything works perfectly. I appreciate your intention Hrothgar.

Hope it can help future generations...

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, but what do we do when the string has to be more than 255 char, as the code does let you do it.  perhaps writing it to a sheet and using vba to reference to it might work

Comment: you should write short sentences into comment.